# How to calculate the average value in 2 textboxes in C#?

Tags: c#, average, calculator

I need to make a program that calculates 2 numbers that are put in through 2 text boxes (each text box has a number). the program must also calculate the average value, max average value and min average value and then shows it all on each label. The program uses 4 labels (every label shows something different, the first one shows the result, the second one shows the average value,...), 2 textboxes, a button and 2 radio buttons (they can be checked if you need to cumulate or substract the numbers). The program is being made in Windows form application. I dont know how to write the code for the average values. Can anybody help me and write the code?

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnIzracunaj_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rndPlus.Checked)
        {

            lblRezultat.Text = (txtSt1.Text + txtSt2.Text).ToString();


        }
        else if (rndMinus.Checked)
        {

            lblRezultat.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(txtSt1.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(txtSt2.Text)).ToString();

        }



    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you know the basic math? If you do, you can easily solve this average, min and max values..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((Convert.ToDouble(txtSt1.Text) + Convert.ToDouble(txtSt2.Text)) / 2).ToString();
```